# Find value in multidimensional array then use it to only print sibling values - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

this is the furthest I've gone into looping through and outputting data from arrays. It may be scratching the surface to some but I'm still wrapping my head around the basic concepts of working with arrays.

I have an multidimensional array with two main sets, each one is nested 5 deep.

I've formatted a `var_dump();` of the arrays - so I can see more clearly what's going on.

```
Array ( 
    'set_56aad4d86660c'     => Array ( // first foreach
        'conditions'            => Array ( // second foreach
            '1'                     => Array ( 
                'type'                  => apply_to 
                'args'                  => Array ( 
                    'applies_to'            => roles 
                    'roles'                 => Array ( 
                        '0'                     => administrator 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 

        'rules' => Array ( 
            '1'     => Array ( 
                'from'      => 1 
                'to'        => 4 
                'type'      => fixed_price 
                'amount'    => 10 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    'set_56aad4d867064'     => Array ( 
        'conditions'            => Array ( 
            '1'                     => Array ( 
                'type'                  => apply_to 
                'args'                  => Array ( 
                    'applies_to'            => roles 
                    'roles'                 => Array ( 
                        '0'                     => trader 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
        'rules' => Array ( 
            '1'     => Array ( 
                'from'      => 5 
                'to'        => 10 
                'type'      => fixed_price 
                'amount'    => 5 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

I'm not having an issue looping through and printing any of the values in the array, I've made sure I can print them all.

**Where I'm stuck**

What I'm trying to do is - when an array set has the role of administrator, only output the values in it's corresponding array.

i.e the data in the 'rules' array - 'from', 'to', 'amount'.

I can print the details from all sets but not based on condition (current user)

**Here's where I am so far**

```
// Pull the data
global $post, $product;

// get the current user's details
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// Loop through main rule sets array
$array_rule_sets = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pricing_rules', true);

// Check to see if there are rule sets
if ($array_rule_sets && is_array($array_rule_sets) && sizeof($array_rule_sets) > 0) {

    // Loop through rule sets
    foreach ( $array_rule_sets as $rule_set ) {

        // Get conditions 
        $conditions = $rule_set['conditions'];

        // Loop through conditions
        foreach ( $conditions as $key => $condition ) {

            // Get Roles
            $roles = $condition['args']['roles'];

            // Loop through roles
            foreach ( $roles as $role ) {

                if ( in_array( $role, (array)$current_user->roles ) ) {
                    $role_rules[] = $key; // getting stuck here
                }

            }

            // Loop through rules array and print pricing table values based on key
            foreach ( $rule_set['rules'] as $key => $value ) {
                $tempstring .= $rule_set['rules'][$key]['from']."- ".$rule_set['rules'][$key]['to']."</td>";
                $tempstring .= $rule_set['rules'][$key]['amount'];
            }  

            // Print results
            echo $tempstring;              
        }
    }
}
```

I went through a tutorial which is where a lot of this code came from. It was for a slightly different case but it had enough to start me off.

I spent the day re-building it bit by bit. I've commented where I get stuck.

I'd really appreciate if someone can understand what I'm trying to do and if possible explain to me where I'm going wrong and if it's possible to achieve the desired outcome.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand correctly, you may want to get the `key` of `$rule_set`, ie. change `foreach ( $array_rule_sets as $rule_set )` to `foreach ( $array_rule_sets as $ruleKey => $rule_set )`. Now instead of using `$key` in `$role_rules[] = $key;`, you can access the rules using `$role_rules[] = $array_rule_sets[$ruleKey]['rules'];`

Comment: Thank Sean. Then would I use `[$ruleKey]` in my foreach e.g  `$rule_set['rules'][$ruleKey]['amount']`?

Comment: No. `$ruleKey` would contain `'set_56aad4d86660c'`.

Comment: Okay, I see that now... As you can tell, I'm a little lost now and it's probably time to leave it for the evening. Armed with the set key, It should allow me to only output the data from that set. Not sure I figure out how to incorporate that into my final foreach.

Answer (score 1):

It's taken ages to tap this in on my tab - so I hope it works for you - basically I stored all the set keys which have the users role in an array, then put all rules in an array using the set key as the key.
I then fetch the required data after all the loops have finished.
Here goes:

```
// Pull the data
global $post, $product;

//** NEW: store user set keys and available rules **//
$user_set_keys = array();
$all_rules = array();

// get the current user's details
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// Loop through main rule sets array
$array_rule_sets = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pricing_rules', true);

// Check to see if there are rule sets
if ($array_rule_sets && is_array($array_rule_sets) && sizeof($array_rule_sets) > 0) {

    // Loop through rule sets
    foreach ( $array_rule_sets as $rule_key => $rule_set ) {  // ** UPDATED

       // Get conditions 
       $conditions = $rule_set['conditions'];

        // Loop through conditions
        foreach ( $conditions as $key => $condition ) {

            // Get Roles
            $roles = $condition['args']['roles'];

            // Loop through roles
            foreach ( $roles as $role ) {

                if ( in_array( $role, (array)$current_user->roles ) ) {
                    $user_set_keys[] = $rule_key; // ** UPDATED ** 
                }

            }

        }

        // Loop through rules array and print pricing table values based on key
        foreach ( $rule_set['rules'] as $ruleArray ) {
            $all_rules[$rule_key] = array(
                'from' => $ruleArray['from'],
                'to' => $ruleArray['to'],
                'amount' => $ruleArray['amount']
            );
        }          
    }
}


// all done now show the data here!
foreach($user_set_keys as $user_set){
     print_r($all_rules[$user_set]);
}
```

Answer to your comment:

If you really don't want the final loop the you could change your second loop to this - I'm not 100% without being able to run, but I'm sure my logic is right:

```
  // Loop through rules array and print pricing table values based on key
    foreach ( $rule_set['rules'] as $ruleArray ) {
         if(in_array($rule_key, $user_set_keys)){
              print_r($ruleArray);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for this. I'm away from the comp now, I'll test in the morning and upvote on success. Cheers

Comment: Jason, thank you again. This solution worked. I'd really like to understand why we had to build an array on the second to last loop? What I'm asking is, is this possible without creating it. I can see now that it works to pull the data in. If I have the output inside the main foreach I'll get duplicates, is this right?

Comment: Also - `$all_rules[$user_set]` only gives me the one round of values, unless I'm using it wrong. I'm going through it using `foreach($user_set_keys as $user_set) {` then using `$all_rules[$user_set]['value']` to output.

Comment: Basically the 1st loop finds all keys (set_56aad4d86660c) which the current user meets the conditions. 2nd loop gathers all rules and organises them by the key. 3rd loop shows the rules by using the keys gathered in the first loop - it is possible to remove the array in the 2nd loop - but why would you? I've basically parsed $array_rule_sets into 2 separate easier to work with arrays - but i'll update my answer to show it can be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102157/discussion-between-johnmccarthy-and-jason-butler).

Comment: Sorry - cant chat this time... got a ton of work to get through! clients counting on me!

Comment: any chance you could mark my answer? Maybe give an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then I think this is what you need to change :

```
 // Loop through rules array and print pricing table values based on key
 // foreach ( $rule_set['rules'] as $key => $value ) { // remove this and replace with....
 for($i=0; $i<count($role_rules); $i++){
    $key = $role_rules[$i];
    $tempstring .= $rule_set['rules'][$key]['from']."- ".$rule_set['rules'][$key]['to']."</td>";
    $tempstring .= $rule_set['rules'][$key]['amount'];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I tried your example but nothing changed. The loop still prints values associated with both rule set arrays.

Comment: I also think you have a } in the wrong place ... shouldnt the third one from the bottom be placed BEFORE your final loop ( or it would cause duplicates on multiple conditions)

Comment: Ive spotted your issue! the keys are not unique causing both rule sets to be displayed. The only unique keys you have is set_56aad4d86660c and set_56aad4d867064 you'll need to add these - I'll see if I can fix this before bed

Comment: Thanks Jason! That's what Sean was saying, but I couldn't get my head around implementing it. I really appreciate your help. As for the `}` in the wrong place, I think you're right... I'll test.